# Where is the shift/reduce conflict in this yacc grammar?

Tags: compiler-construction, grammar, bison, yacc, shift-reduce-conflict

I'm writing a parser for a language called C-. I have to write the grammar so its not ambiguous and I can't use any %prec statements in Bison. I've corrected all but 1 shift/reduce conflict and I can't figure out where it is. Any ideas? My .output file gives the following info for where its occurring:

```
State 163

   44 matched: IF '(' simpleExp ')' matched . ELSE matched
   46 unmatched: IF '(' simpleExp ')' matched .
   48          | IF '(' simpleExp ')' matched . ELSE unmatched

    ELSE  shift, and go to state 169

    ELSE      [reduce using rule 46 (unmatched)]
    $default  reduce using rule 46 (unmatched)
```

The grammar:

```
stmt                : selectStmt
                    ;

expStmt             : exp ';'
                    | ';'

compoundStmt        : '{' localDecls stmtList '}'
                    ;  

stmtList            : stmtList stmt
                    |
                    ;

otherStmt           : compoundStmt
                    | expStmt
                    | iterStmt
                    | returnStmt
                    | breakStmt
                    ;     

localDecls          : localDecls scopedVarDecl
                    |
                    ;

selectStmt          : matched
                    | unmatched
                    ;
                
matched             : IF '(' simpleExp ')' matched ELSE matched
                    | otherStmt
                    ;

unmatched           : IF '(' simpleExp ')' matched
                    | IF '(' simpleExp ')' unmatched
                    | IF '(' simpleExp ')' matched ELSE unmatched
                    ;
                    
iterStmt            : WHILE simpleExp DO selectStmt
                    | FOR ID '=' iterRange DO selectStmt
                    ;

iterRange           : simpleExp
                    | simpleExp TO simpleExp
                    | simpleExp TO simpleExp BY simpleExp
                    ;

returnStmt          : RETURN ';'
                    | RETURN exp ';'
                    ;

breakStmt           : BREAK ';'
                    ;
```

Comment: The matched/unmatched is supposed to eliminate the dangling else problem. If I remove that statement, there would be no way to have an unmatched if statement after a matched if else. So "if else if" would be impossible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that it is not only `if` statements which can be "matched". An iteration  statement which ends with an unmatched statement is just as unmatched as an `if` statement which ends with an unmatched statement. That's what "matched" means.

So you have to divide your iterative statements into `matched` and `unmatched` variants. (This is why most people use precedence or expect declarations to deal with dangling else.)

Here's a simple example in case it becomes useful in the future. (Many of the non-terminals haven't been changed, so their definitions have been omitted. I also expanded a lot of abbreviations.)

```
statement: matched
         | unmatched
/* Statements which could have been extended with an else clause,
 * but haven't been. An unmatched statement can be the body of an
 * unmatched compound statement, which includes an `if` statement
 * whose `else` clause is unmatched. Unmatched also includes `if`
 * statements without an `else` clause.
 */
unmatched: "if" '(' simpleExp ')' statement
         | "if" '(' simpleExp ')' matched "else" unmatched
         | "while" '(' simpleExp ')' "do" unmatched
         | "for" IDENT '=' iterRange "do" unmatched
/* Statements which cannot be extended with an else clause.
 * In other words, in a `matched` every `else` matches some `if`.
 * Only `matched` statements can come between `if` and `else`, because
 * an unmatched statement would grab the `else` for itself.
 */
matched  : "if" '(' simpleExp ')' matched "else" matched
         | "while" '(' simpleExp ')' "do" matched
         | "for" IDENT '=' iterRange "do" matched
         | expStatement
         | returnStatement
         | breakStatement
         | '{' localDeclarations statementList '}'
```